# Is there a way to get attributes // associations by previously defined Sequelize Model?

Tags: model, sequelize.js

I need to get some data by previously defined Sequelize Model.

What I need:

```
* attributes list
  * attribute name
  * attribute type (INTEGER, STRING,...)
  * was it generated by association method?
* list of associations
  * association type (belongsTo, hasMany, ...)
```

For some reason it's rather hard to inspect Sequelize models in console:

```
> db.sequelize.models.Payment
Payment // <- it's valid Sequelize Model {Object}, however its not inspectable

> db.sequelize.models.Payment.attributes
...
type:
 { type: { values: [Object] },
   values: [ 'cash', 'account', 'transfer' ],
   Model: Payment,
   fieldName: 'type',
   _modelAttribute: true,
   field: 'type' },
sum: 
 { type: 
    { options: [Object],
      _length: undefined,
      _zerofill: undefined,
      _decimals: undefined,
      _precision: undefined,
      _scale: undefined,
      _unsigned: undefined },
   Model: Payment,
   fieldName: 'sum',
   _modelAttribute: true,
   field: 'sum' },
 ...
```

As you see, there is no actual info about fields types. The same happens with associations.

So, is there any reliable "official" way to extract this data from Model class without digging and reversing  object?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try `Payment.rawAttributes`, which is an object with property name as key, and an object with property details. `property.type.key` is a string with the type.

`Payment.associations` is  an object of associations - the key is the name, and each association will have an `associationType` property - you can also do `association instanceof sequelize.Association.BelongsTo` etc.

Comment: THANK YOU. After thoroughly searching Stack Overflow, I started troving through the Sequelize code and got access to my model's attributes. Couldn't figure out how to read the DataType when it showed up as `ABSTRACT { length: 255 }`. Both of the above work.

Comment: To get the type as a string used on your database, you can do `ModelName.rawAttributes.propertyName.type.toSql()`

Comment: Thanks! Just used it today. Is there documentation for this mysterious "type" object and all the properties/methods it contains?

Comment: @NobleUplift I don't see any docs, but the type is `AbstractDataType` and the code for it is here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/types/lib/data-types.d.ts

Comment: I use `model.rawAttributes.id.autoIncrement` on `beforeValidate` in `new Sequelize` to automatically add `id` when `autoIncrement` is false. `rawAttributes` is deprecated in v7 though.

Answer (score 7):

### Sequelize v6

`rawAttributes()` method is now deprecated, use `getAttributes()` method instead. [Documentation](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-getAttributes)

Example usage:

```js
import models from "./src/models/index.js"
import User from "./src/models/User.js"

console.log(models.sequelize.model('user').getAttributes())
console.log(User.getAttributes())
```

Comment: If you only want the Object keys you can do: `Object.keys(User.getAttributes())`