# Return list of attributes from a Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am using Sequelize Typescript v6.  I already have a model with a lot of features and I want to get a list of those features.

```js
const attrs = attributes(MyModel)
console.log(attrs)
// [col0Name, col1Name, col2Name,...]
```

I see that Sequelize Typescript has a way to Type a list as a set of parameters for a model [Getting a models attributes](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/#getting-a-models-attributes). But I cannot use this as a function.

```js
const modelAttributes = Attributes<MyModel>
//'Attributes' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I tried `MyModel.attributes` but that doesn't exist either. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
MyModel.getAttributes()
```

Also, `.rawAttributes` seems to be a way as well. [Is there a way to get attributes // associations by previously defined Sequelize Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858334/is-there-a-way-to-get-attributes-associations-by-previously-defined-sequelize)

To get a list of strings I used

```js
const myAttrs = Object.keys(MyModel.rawAttributes)
```